# Is there a difference to refer to a document with vs without forward-slash in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, I notice we can do `PUT mydoc` or `PUT /mydoc`

And to delete, I can do either `DELETE mydoc` or `DELETE /mydoc` regardless if I PUT them with a forward-slash or not.

Is there any difference if I use the forward-slash or not?

If there is no difference, which is a more conventional approach?

Comment: can you add example ?

Comment: The example is given, i.e. `PUT mydoc` and `PUT /mydoc`, what's the difference?

Comment: yeah but how you are trying and where you read that both format works? I use postman and it doesn't work and I hope mydoc is your `index name`

Answer (score 0):

When working in the [Kibana Console](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/console-kibana.html), the conventional approach is to **include** the leading slash in the [URI path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3), just like in the spec of the [Create index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#indices-create-api-request), [Delete index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html#delete-index-api-request), and elsewhere.

Now, these URI paths are useless until they're [concatenated](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/d9828c22d54701e7c67dbb0bed4e3862b2feae9e/src/plugins/console/public/application/models/sense_editor/sense_editor.ts#L472) with *some* ES host, i.e. `http://localhost:9200` → `http://localhost:9200/mydoc`.

If you include a leading slash in the path, the Kibana editor will [ensure](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/d9828c22d54701e7c67dbb0bed4e3862b2feae9e/src/plugins/console/public/lib/es/es.ts#L66) that it's stripped before it's combined with the host (which ideally shouldn't end with a slash):

```
export function constructESUrl(baseUri: string, path: string) {
  baseUri = baseUri.replace(/\/+$/, '');
  path = path.replace(/^\/+/, '');                  //  <----
  return baseUri + '/' + path;
}
```

---

On one hand, the leading slash improves the readability of where the HTTP method ends and where the URI path starts. See, in theory, these two are perfectly valid commands:

```
PUT put
DELETE delete
```

but these are objectively more readable (however unfortunate):

```
PUT /put
DELETE /delete
```

But **more importantly**, I think it has to do with what's called "absolute-path reference". More on this in [this Webmasters Stackexchange thread](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/56844).

Comment: Did this answer your question @Elye?